# How to plot two variables of the same abscissa in the same line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, aes, geom

I want to plot two variables of the same abscissa in a same line. If it is the same abscissa, the two variables will be displayed on the same abscissa. But I want to keep them separate without affecting the coherence of the abscissa.

Here is the original data:

```
df<-structure(list(Bloc = c(7, 7, 8, 8, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 5, 5, 7, 
                            7, 8, 8, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 5, 5), Pos_heliaphen = c("W16", "W17", 
                                                                                "W36", "W37", "X02", "X03", "W16", "W17", "W36", "W37", "X02", 
                                                                                "X03", "W16", "W17", "W36", "W37", "X02", "X03", "W16", "W17", 
                                                                                "W36", "W37", "X02", "X03"), traitement = c("WS", "WW", "WW", 
                                                                                                                            "WS", "WS", "WW", "WS", "WW", "WW", "WS", "WS", "WW", "WS", "WW", 
                                                                                                                            "WW", "WS", "WS", "WW", "WS", "WW", "WW", "WS", "WS", "WW"), 
                   Variete = c("Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", 
                               "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", 
                               "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", 
                               "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", 
                               "Blancas"), Date_obs = c("D1_27/05/2021", "D1_27/05/2021", 
                                                        "D1_27/05/2021", "D1_27/05/2021", "D1_27/05/2021", "D1_27/05/2021", 
                                                        "D2_28/05/2021", "D2_28/05/2021", "D2_28/05/2021", "D2_28/05/2021", 
                                                        "D2_28/05/2021", "D2_28/05/2021", "D3_29/05/2021", "D3_29/05/2021", 
                                                        "D3_29/05/2021", "D3_29/05/2021", "D3_29/05/2021", "D3_29/05/2021", 
                                                        "D4_30/05/2021", "D4_30/05/2021", "D4_30/05/2021", "D4_30/05/2021", 
                                                        "D4_30/05/2021", "D4_30/05/2021"), P_av_arros = c(0.51, 0.53, 
                                                                                                          0.55, 0.57, 0.59, 0.61, 0.63, 0.65, 0.67, 0.69, 0.71, 0.73, 
                                                                                                          0.75, 0.77, 0.79, 0.81, 0.83, 0.85, 0.87, 0.89, 0.91, 0.93, 
                                                                                                          0.95, 0.97), FTSW_apres_arros = c(0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 
                                                                                                                                            0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 
                                                                                                                                            1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09, 1.1, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14
                                                                                                          )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                      -24L))
```

I gained this code from previous questions. But this is when the abscissa is in the format of the date. Now I'm wondering what should I do if the abscissa is not a date, just a non-consecutive value?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

labels <- df %>% 
  select(Bloc, Pos_heliaphen) %>% 
  distinct(Bloc, Pos_heliaphen) %>% 
  group_by(Bloc) %>% 
  summarise(Pos_heliaphen = paste(Pos_heliaphen, collapse = "-")) %>% 
  tibble::deframe()

df %>%
  mutate(Date_obs = as.POSIXct(lubridate::dmy(Date_obs))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(6:7) %>%
  mutate(Date_obs = if_else(name == "FTSW_apres_arros", 
                            Date_obs + 43200, Date_obs)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, value, colour = factor(Bloc), shape = traitement, 
             linetype = traitement, group = interaction(Bloc, traitement))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = labels, guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%d/%m/%Y", date_breaks = "day") +
  labs(y = expression(paste("FTSW"))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

I hope I can get this graph:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Allan Cameron I'm not sure if this description is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, it is going to be easiest to stick to dealing with "proper" dates and just recreating the labels for the x axis.

```r
df %>%
  tidyr::separate(Date_obs, c("Obs", "Date_obs"), sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(Date_obs = as.POSIXct(lubridate::dmy(Date_obs))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(7:8) %>%
  mutate(Date_obs = if_else(name == "FTSW_apres_arros", 
                            Date_obs + 43200, Date_obs)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, value, colour = factor(Bloc), shape = traitement, 
             linetype = traitement, group = interaction(Bloc, traitement))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = labels, guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = ~ paste0("D", seq_along(.x) - 1, "_", 
                                     strftime(.x, "%d/%m/%Y")),
                   date_breaks = "day") +
  labs(y = expression(paste("FTSW"))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]